# Difference between $() and () in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix, subshell

When I type `ls -l $(echo file)` output from bracket (which is just simple echo'ing) is taken and passed to external `ls -l` command. It equals to simple `ls -l file`.

When I type `ls -l (echo file)` we have error because one cannot nest `()` inside external command.

Can someone help me understand the difference between `$()` and `()` ?

Comment: One is a syntax error; the other is not. They pretty much have nothing in common.

Comment: What did you expect `ls -l (echo file)` to do?

Answer (score 31):

`$(cmd)`  substitutes the result of `cmd` as a string, whereas `(cmd; cmd)` run a list of commands in a subprocess.

If you want to put the output of one or more commands into a variable use the $( cmd ) form.

However if you want to run a number of commands and treat them as a single unit
use the () form.

The latter is useful when you want to run a set of commands in the background:

```
(git pull; make clean; make all) &
```

Comment: sorry, but still i dont get it... </br>
`variable=$(ls; ps)`  </br>
`echo $variable`  and eveyrting is correct , but </br>
`variable=(ls; ps)` gives syntax error </br>
`(ls; ps)` executes both commands </br>
`variable=(ls ps); echo $variable ` gives "ls" literally

Answer (score 10):

They are different, but there is a mnemonic relationship between them.

`(...)` is a command that starts a new subshell in which shell commands are run.

`$(...)` is an expression that starts a new subshell, whose expansion is the standard output produced by the commands it runs.

This is similar to another command/expression pair in `bash`: `((...))` is an arithmetic statement, while `$((...))` is an arithmetic expression.

Answer (score 9):

Those are different things.

`$()` evaluates an expression (executing a command) like `` (backticks)

```
> (echo ls)
ls

> $(echo ls)
file1  file2

> `echo ls`
file1  file2

> echo $(echo ls)
ls
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `echo $(echo ls)`

Answer (score 1):

`()` is also used to create array in bash. See `man bash`:

> Arrays  are  assigned  to using compound assignments of the form name=(value1 ... valuen), where each value is of the form [subscript]=string.

```
$ arr=(a b c 'd f' e)
$ declare -p arr 
declare -a arr=([0]="a" [1]="b" [2]="c" [3]="d f" [4]="e")
```